# WSO2 APIM: User Store Encryption Sometimes Fails

Tags: wso2-api-manager

We have a scripted (ansible) deployment of APIM 4.2.0.  We have an external LDAP user store.  The deployment does as follows

- Templates out the deployment.toml file
- Uses WSO2's `ciphertool.sh` to encrypt passwords in the config files
- Templates the user store definition as `MYENV.enc` (in `repository/deployment/server/userstores`) including the password to the LDAP (in plain text)
- Restarts the WSO2 APIM Service

What should happen then is that on startup, WSO2 will

- Create a `MYENV.xml` (based on `MYENV.enc` but with the password encrypted)
- Delete `MYENV.enc`

This is usually what happens.  However, sometimes after running the ansible, we cannot log in and when we go in as admin we see no users from the user store.  The `wso2carbon.log` shows `javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]; remaining name ''` and basically it hasn't got the right credentials.

What seems to have happened is that it has encrypted the password and created the `MYENV.xml` (and deleted the `MYENV.enc`) however, while the `MYENV.xml` contains the encrypted password it looks like this:

```
<Property name="ConnectionPassword">Long encrypted password redacted from example</Property>
```

instead of

```
    <Property name="ConnectionPassword" encrypted="true">Long encrypted password redacted from example</Property>
```

I.e. it is missing the `encrypted="true"` attribute!  It has encrypted the password but it is pretending it isn't.  When I manually recreated the `MYENV.enc` file (with the plain text password) and restarted the service, the `MYENV.xml` file it then created on startup contained exactly the same encrypted password but had the `encrypted="true"` property and everything worked.

As I said, this doesn't happen every time.  Any ideas where to stat looking or how to handle it?  Should I create the `MYENV.enc` before running the `ciphertool.sh` - would that make any difference?